# How can I model a complex relation between two resources?

Tags: semantic-web, rdfs

Consider having a relation/predicate between 2 resources: 
<#A> <#isRelatedTo> <#B>.

I want to add properties to the <#isRelatedTo> relation: relation strength, description, etc.

So I could model this:

1. Define instances of the predicate and add properties to those instances similar to what is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131025133939/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3597/is-the-predicate-in-an-rdf-triple-a-class-or-an-instance)
2. Use quad store so I have an unique id for the triple and add properties to the triple 
   (problem is that i have to use a triple store because of database restriction)
3. Define a class of relations (isRelatedToClass) that have <#From>, <#To>, <#RelStrength>, <#Description> properties. Create instances of that class that represent a relation and connect A and B.

e.g.:

> ```
> <#isRelatedToInstance1> <rdf:type> <#isRelatedToClass>  
> <#isRelatedToInstance1> <#isRelated/From> <#A>  
> <#isRelatedToInstance1> <#isRelated/To>   <#B>  
> <#isRelatedToInstance1> <#isRelated/RelStrength> "2"  
> <#isRelatedToInstance1> <#isRelated/Description> "some desc"
> ```

4 . Other implementations?

Practical examples would be:
- connecting cities/countries by a transportation system where each transport property has it's own properties
- connecting people where I want to say "X knows(since 1955) Y" or "X rated(5 stars) ZProduct"

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. I agree that those are alternatives to the design problem of reifying a relationship so that you can make assertions about it (NB, there's also RDF Reification [http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#reification] itself), but StackOverflow exists to curate good answers to questions. What's your question?

Comment: It seems I forgot about reification. My question was the one i wrote in the title and I provided the implementations I thought possible, and I was expecting an answer to clarify what was the recommended way to solve this, which one to avoid and why.. or in general what are the best practices in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from RDF reification that has been mentioned in the comments, you could do the following: for each pairs `(A,B)` that are in relationship wrt `isRelatedTo`, create a subproperty `isRelatedTo_A_B` for which you specify strength, description, etc.

```
<#A>  <#isRelatedTo_A_B>  <#B> .
<#isRelatedTo_A_B>  rdfs:subPropertyOf  <#isRelatedTo>;
    <#relStrength>  2;
    <#description>  "A is in relation with B"@en .
```

You could even restrict `isRelatedTo_A_B` to hold only for the pair `(A,B)`, with OWL:

```
<#isRelatedTo_A_B>  rdfs:domain  [
    a  owl:Class;
    owl:oneOf  ( <#A> )
];  rdfs:range  [
    a  owl:Class;
    owl:oneOf  ( <#B> )
] .
```

With some care, it would make a valid OWL DL ontology.